# parsing xml file in javascript

Tags: ajax

AM developing a auto completion or suggestion box using AJAX and servlets . My problem is how to parse the XML response in java script to show it in a div tag.My xml response is like contains one parent tag RESULTS , it contains  number of children tags called RESULT.

How to get result values in java script variables.

Comment: Look at [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript/8412989#8412989)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 1):

Take look on this thread: [Parse XML from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410796/parse-xml-from-xmlhttprequest)

I think it contains information you need.